# Julia Threads.@threads doesn't work in a simple example

Tags: julia

I am running a double loop in Julia. The code is quite simple.

```
w = rand(1000,1000)
function regular_demo(w::Array{Float64, 2})
    n = size(w)[1]
    G = zeros(n,n)
    @inbounds for j in 1:n-1
    wjj = w[j, j]
        for i in j+1:n
            wii = w[i, i]
            wij = w[i, j]
            sum = wii + 2wij + 3wjj 
            sum_inverse = inv(sum)
            G[j,j] = G[j,j] + sum_inverse
            G[i,i] = G[i,i] + sum_inverse
            G[i,j] = G[i,j] - sum_inverse
            G[j,i] = G[j,i] - sum_inverse         
        end
    end
G
end
regular_demo(w)
```

```
function thread_demo(w::Array{Float64, 2})
    n = size(w)[1]
    G = zeros(n,n)
    @inbounds Threads.@threads for j in 1:n-1
    wjj = w[j, j]
        for i in j+1:n
            wii = w[i, i]
            wij = w[i, j]
            sum = wii + 2wij + 3wjj 
            sum_inverse = inv(sum)
            G[j,j] = G[j,j] + sum_inverse
            G[i,i] = G[i,i] + sum_inverse
            G[i,j] = G[i,j] - sum_inverse
            G[j,i] = G[j,i] - sum_inverse         
        end
    end
G
end
thread_demo(w)
```

The only difference between regular_demo(w) and thread_demo(w) is @inbounds Threads.@threads in line 4 of the function. If I run both regular_demo(w) and thread_demo(w) for the same matrix w. The output matrix G are different. How can I implement thread in thread_demo(w) for the purpose of getting the same output matrix G as regular_demo(w).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct function should look like below

```
function thread_demo(w::Array{Float64, 2})
    n = size(w)[1]
    G = [Threads.Atomic{Float64}(0.0) for i in 1:n, j in 1:n]
    a =  n % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0
    @inbounds Threads.@threads for j2 in 1:n-1
        j = j2 % 2 == 1 ? j2 : n - j2 + a
        wjj = w[j, j]
        for i in j+1:n
            sum_inverse = inv(w[i, i] + 2w[i, j] + 3wjj )
            for i in 1:1000
                sum_inverse = inv(sum_inverse)
            end #used for performance testing
            Threads.atomic_add!(G[j,j], sum_inverse)
            Threads.atomic_add!(G[j,i], -sum_inverse)
            Threads.atomic_add!(G[i,i], sum_inverse)
            Threads.atomic_add!(G[i,j], -sum_inverse)
        end
    end
    G
end
```

The following two things needed to be corrected in your code:

- `Threads.@threads` slices the elements into equal parts, however the size of your inner loop decreases with larger `j` values. This calls for recalculation of `j` to have a more or less equal job distribution across threads
- Your `G` identifiers overlaps for various values of `j`. This means you need to synchronize between threads for operations on the same data. You can use locks (e.g. `Threads.SpinLock`) or atomic values for this. Here I use the atomic values because they are more natural in this example.

You can check that my code works by running the following test:

```
gg1 = regular_demo(w);
gg2 = thread_demo(w);
@assert all(gg1 .≈ getproperty.(gg2, :value))
```

You need to use the approximate equal operator because parallelism can change the order of arithmetic operations and you get slightly different results.

Now the problem is that atomics are expensive. My code will take much longer to execute than your `regular_demo` function because coordination between threads is required and the operations inside your loop are very cheap. However, most likely your scenario is much more complicated than this MWE and with my code you will observe significant performance gain (for testing parallelism you could try to add something like `for i in 1:1000; sum_inverse = inv(sum_inverse); end` inside the inner loop and see yourself).

Note that In order for multithreading to work in Julia you need to set the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` variable with the number of desired threads (not larger than the number of logical CPU cores).

Windows:

```
set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Linux:

```
export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Note that some IDEs set such as Juno by default set the number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores.

Last but not least, you can test your configuration by running `Threads.nthreads()`:

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
4
```

Comment: Bravo!  Excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still have a question. If w = rand(1001,1001), it seems that the result by function thread_demo doesn't match the result by function regular_demo. It seems that the code only work if n = size(w)[1] is an even number. What if n = size(w)[1] is an odd number? In reality, n can be even or odd number.  How can I modify function thread_demo so that it works for both even number n and odd number n. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I figure it out. we can add the code at the second line of the function thread_demo: if n % 2 == 1 a = 2 else a = 1 end. We can change line 5 as j = j2 % 2 == a ? j2 : n - j2.  Now function thread_demo works for both even number n and odd number n. Thanks for your instruction!

Comment: @Mizzle thank you - I added line to correctly work for both even and odd sizes of `w`.

Comment: Multi threading is not a magical spell. It will not automagically make your code run faster. You must make sure your code can run in parallel and do not write to the same location at the same time. Otherwise you will need to use locks or atomic writes to ensure that you do not cobble your internal program logic.